# Repairing scratched black border on the back side of the imac screen

Tags: imac, hardware, screen, repair

I tried to replace the imac screen and accidentally scratched the black frame that comes on the back side of the screen around the lcd area. Just forgot about it and now it has some really noticeable and visible scratches. I thought it would be easy to repair just by dyeing it out, but nope. I tried different kinds of paints but none works. They all looks gray, significantly lighter than original. Btw, original border looks like a kinda adhesive tape or coating, not a dye, so I tried a different kinds of black tapes with heat gun, like insulating and so on, as well as different kinds of dissolved plastics - nothing works, all are grey, not black. The closest and darkest dye was some acrylic paint which still looks grey and still significantly lighter than original.

I'm looking for advise - how to repair it? And is it possible at all?

Thank you!